# SqlAlchemy recursive query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a Post Model that has 3 fields

- id
- parent_id
- note

is it possible to retrieve result like this with sqlalchemy query?

```
{ id: 1, parent_id: 0, note: 'Note1', children: [
    {id: 5, parent_id: 1, note: 'Reply1', children: [
        {id: 8, parent_id: 5, note: 'Reply reply', children: []}
       ]
    },
    {id: 6, parent_id: 1, note: 'Reply2', children: []},
    {id: 7, parent_id: 1, note: 'Reply3', children: []} 
  ]
},
  id: 2, parent_id: 0, note: 'Note2', children: [{}]
  id: 3, parent_id: 0, note: 'Note3', children: [{}]
}
```

i tried this sqlalchemy

```
id= 1 
hierarchy = db.session.query(Post).filter(Post.id == id).cte(name="hierarchy", recursive=True)

parent = aliased(hierarchy, name="p")
children = aliased(Post, name="c")

hierarchy = hierarchy.union_all(db.session.query(children).filter(children.parent_id == parent.c.id))

result = db.session.query(Post).select_entity_from(hierarchy).all()
```

which gives me rows like this (probably because I used union_all?)

```
results = [
{id: 1, parent_id: 0, note: 'Note1',
{id: 5, parent_id: 1, note: 'Reply1',
{id: 8, parent_id: 5, note: 'Reply reply'}
]
```

Is only option I have is to iterate over results recursively and make it manually? (to have nested `children` column with its children as list)

Comment: Getting recursive structures out of a relational database is not trivial. It usually need joins that get more complex per number of levels. You should consider creating the recursive structure in Python code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get dict of lists from relationship in sqlalchemy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38762607/how-to-get-dict-of-lists-from-relationship-in-sqlalchemy)